# NSTask (whoami) to string, to NSTask (cp) failed - Swift

Tags: swift, nstask, cp

I am trying to make a copy of the AddressBook of my Mac to a save place before archiving it. Here is my code :

```
 // whoami
                let whoam : NSTask = NSTask()
                whoam.launchPath = "/usr/bin/whoami"

            // pipe whoami| NSString
                let UltimPipe : NSPipe = NSPipe()
                let UltimPipeLisible : NSFileHandle = UltimPipe.fileHandleForReading
                whoam.standardOutput = UltimPipe
            // lancement
                whoam.launch()

            // lecture de la sortie
                let DonSortie : NSData = UltimPipeLisible.readDataToEndOfFile()
                let Sortie : String? = String(data: DonSortie, encoding:
                    NSUTF8StringEncoding)

                if Sortie == nil
                {
                    print("Résultat de sortie non-valide")
                    let MonAlerte:NSAlert = NSAlert()
                    MonAlerte.messageText = "Aucun élement trouvé."
                    MonAlerte.informativeText = ""
                    MonAlerte.runModal()
                    exit(1)
                }

                let ligne : String = Sortie!
                print (ligne)

                let source = "/Users/"+ligne+"/Library/Application Support/AddressBook"
                let destin = "/Users/"+ligne+"/Desktop/test/"


//cp
                let duTache : NSTask = NSTask()
                duTache.launchPath = "/bin/cp"
                duTache.arguments = [ "-r", source, " ", destin ]
                print (duTache.arguments)

                let ifcPipe : NSPipe = NSPipe()
                duTache.standardOutput = ifcPipe

            // lancement
                duTache.launch()
```

The returned error is :

```
usage: cp [-R [-H |...]
```

It look like I have a syntax problem, and, when I do a print of the arguments of duTache (print (duTache.arguments)), the answer is :

```
Optional(["-r", "/Users/username\n/Library/Application Support/AddressBook", " ", "/Users/username\n/Desktop/test/"])
```

Maybe if I remove the "\n" present after the username the operation could be completed? Does anyone knows how to do that?

Thank you for reading my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var ligne = "username\n"
print(ligne,0)
/*
username
0
*/
let newLine = ligne.removeAtIndex(ligne.endIndex.predecessor()) // newLine is "\n"
print(ligne,0)
/*
username 0
*/
```

Comment: I'll try this. I'll let you know. Thank U.

Comment: removeAtIndex is working but the result is made of type Character and I need the type String. Downcast is refused (always failed). Any idea how to convert it to String?

Comment: you don't have to use newLine (in newLine is just \n). ligne is now without \n and has String type .... so use it like before.

Comment: The result is now like this :

Comment: var ligne : String = Sortie!
            print (ligne)
            let line = ligne.removeAtIndex(ligne.endIndex.predecessor())

            
            let source = "/Users/"+ligne+"/Library/Application Support/AddressBook"
            let destin = "/Users/"+ligne+"/Desktop/test/"
           
        
    //cp
            let duTache : NSTask = NSTask()
            duTache.launchPath = "/bin/cp"
            duTache.arguments = [ "-r", source, " ", destin ]
            print (duTache.arguments)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Long live StackOverflow!

Comment: Due to the new syntax, there is a little difference (to avoid warning, the line must be changed to :     _ = ligne.removeAtIndex(ligne.endIndex.predecessor())

Comment: _ = ligne.removeAtIndex(ligne.endIndex.predecessor())

Comment: ligne.removeAtIndex(ligne.endIndex.predecessor()) is enough! I just gave you 'more complete' example. the removeAtIndex return what did you remove from string.

Answer (score 0):

```
import Foundation

func execute(command: String, args: [String]) -> String {

    let task = NSTask()

    task.launchPath = command
    task.arguments = args

    let pipe = NSPipe()
    task.standardOutput = pipe
    task.launch()

    let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
    let output: String? = String(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    task.waitUntilExit()

    return output ?? ""

}


print(execute("/bin/ls", args: ["-alsp"]))
print(execute("/bin/ls", args: []))


execute("/usr/bin/say", args: ["Hello World!"])
```

if you find how to process exceptions ( try some stupid command like /bin/lss ), let me know! I need to check the documentation first ...

Comment: Is the exemple above a better way to use NSTask?

Comment: I 'll need some time to implement it but in a Playground it is doing the job. It might also solve the error I get when using "cp" (cp:  : No such file or directory)? Thank you.

Comment: I made some test inside a playground but commands are not working properly (cp, or even ls which sometimes work, sometimes don't (depending on the path chosen)). Inside a project, all the command are working but cp is reporting : " cp:  : No such file or directory" (although it is doing the copy job!). Can I ignore this error?